# Loaded content via AJAX, go to next page, go back, content is no longer there

Tags: jquery, ajax, back-button, browser-history

I have a button on a page that says "Add Locations". You click it, and form elements appear from an AJAX request. When you submit the page, and go back, those form elements no longer exist on the page.

Is it possible to keep the 'state' of the page when the user goes back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you save it in a cookie or the `local-storage` for HTML5.

**HTML - Javascript - web development are stateless.**

Answer (score 0):

you can implement `Dom Storage` feature:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0):

You could run the AJAX request on pageLoad
otherwise you could use Session variables or Cookies to preserve your data and reload it when the user navigates back to the page

Comment: I don't think you hit the session when clicking the back button.